# matplotlib: Adding North arrow to a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have used the following code to add the North arrow to a map:

```py
def add_north_arrow(ax):

        # Define the coordinates and dimensions of the arrow in display space
        x_tail = 0.05 * ax.figure.bbox.width  # 5% of the figure width from the left
        y_tail = 0.05 * ax.figure.bbox.height  # 5% of the figure height from the bottom
        dx = 0  # No horizontal displacement
        dy = 0.05 * ax.figure.bbox.height  # 10% of the figure height vertical displacement

        # Draw an arrow with a text "N" above it using annotation
        ax.annotate("N", xy=(x_tail + dx/2, y_tail + dy + dy/10), xycoords="figure pixels",
                ha="center", va="center", fontsize=20)
        ax.annotate("", xy=(x_tail + dx, y_tail + dy), xycoords="figure pixels",
                xytext=(x_tail, y_tail), textcoords="figure pixels",
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>", facecolor="black"))
```

The output is like this:
[image]

The problem is that I cannot draw the N and the arrow in the top part of the axis. If I mess with the coordinates, my code does not draw the N and the arrow at all! How can I solve this issue?

And btw, is there a way to overlay the N on the arrow?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
def add_north_arrow(ax):

  py =0.8 * ax.figure.bbox.height
  px =0.05 * ax.figure.bbox.width

  # Draw an arrow with a text "N" above it using annotation
  ax.annotate("N", xy=(px, py), fontsize=20, xycoords="figure pixels")
  ax.annotate("",  xy=(px,  py), xytext=(px, py-30),xycoords="figure pixels",
          arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-|>", facecolor="black"))
```

P.S.

You have to adjust a bit the size and the offset. I tested the code with this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols =1)
ax.imshow(np.zeros((300, 300)))
add_north_arrow(ax)
plt.show()
```

[image]